# Eclipse Keyword Index Issue

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a problem with the Eclipse Keyword Index for a Remote Infocenter. I have the following index.xml file (also specified as the primary index in my plugin.xml):

```
<index>
    <entry keyword="Electricity">
        <topic href="electricity.html"/>
    </entry>
</index>
```

When clicking the index tab (from Help->Help Contents) i get the following exception in my Eclipse Console:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.help.internal.Topic
    at org.eclipse.help.internal.base.remote.RemoteIndexParser.parse(RemoteIndexParser.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.help.internal.base.remote.RemoteIndexProvider.getIndexContributions(RemoteIndexProvider.java:54)

The remote infocenter contains a plugin.xml, index.xml, toc.xml.
Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: 3.5 ok. It would be interesting to check if this has been fixed in 3.5.1

Comment: Yes, thank you for the idea! I will try to test in 3.5.1 also. In the same time, I think i was going the wrong way with using a plugin.xml for a remote infocenter, because it seems to be ignored. I appears only a simple "index" file is needed, written in xml syntax, but with some extra tags inside (adding those stopped my error). The documentation for developing a remote infocenter (files needed etc.) seems to be not that rich :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an older question, but i forgot to add what fixed my issue: as i recall, it was what i added in my last comment to the question description - so having the needed files and proper xml attribute editing for index and table of contents, for the specific eclipse version, in case the help system xml attributes change.
[This link](http://www.keycontent.org/tiki-index.php?page=eclipse%20help%20system) was helpful in my case.

But in case you run into similar issues and seem to have correct xml syntax, i think you should refer to VonC's answer and indicated thread.

Answer (score 1):

What version of eclipse are you using?
The 3.4 or early 3.5 version of 2008 might still have an issue with remote help, as illustrated by [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.ua/msg00644.html).
Do you reproduce that with an eclipse 3.5.1 ?

> What is happening is that an index entry in a remote toc does not have a label attribute and it is trying to look up the href in the TOC.
>   We have tested the remote index but may not have hit on that particular situation in our testing.

Comment: I am using Eclipse 3.5. It is about a remote infocenter for Eclipse. Sorry I forgot to mention this.